# Turning an ERC721 mint contract to store funds and accept payments

Tags: function, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

hope all is well.

I have been following Dapp University tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-6ruqmNS3o?start=2111) to make a mintable NFT pairs game. I am now trying to turn the contract to charge a small fee on top of the gas fee for every new token minted to and store the funds in the smart contract to withdraw later to a personal wallet.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./ERC721Full.sol";

contract MemoryToken is ERC721Full{
 address public shopOwner;
 constructor() ERC721Full('Memory Token', 'MEMORY') public {

}

  function balanceOf()  public view returns(uint){
   return address(this).balance;
   }

 function withdraw()  public payable {
   require(msg.sender == shopOwner, 'only shopOwner can withdraw');
   msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

  }

  function mint(address _to, string memory _tokenURI ) public payable 
    returns(bool){
     // require(msg.value >= 2 ether, "Not enough ETH : check price.");
     uint _tokenId= totalSupply().add(1);
     _mint(_to, _tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(_tokenId, _tokenURI);
    return true;

    }
  }
```

I have added `balanceOf()` function to view the funds accumulated and a `withdraw()` function for only the shopOwner to withdraw the accumulated funds. In addition, I have turned the `mint()` function to be payable and added a require statement to make an added charge (0.05 ether) to the player. However, when a user makes a pair match (click the link to see the pair match: https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-6ruqmNS3o?start=5144), the price charged seems to be only the gas fees. It is also throwing the following error.

The mint function stored in ERC721Full can be seen below:

```
function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
    require(to != address(0), "ERC721: mint to the zero address");
    require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");

    _tokenOwner[tokenId] = to;
    _ownedTokensCount[to].increment();

    emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
}
```

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Not enough ETH sent: check price.","code":-32000,"data":{"0x5cadd81f6d91f1ef5547c4c841c9788978eb5a9a590b25765081d48a824a1c99":

> Uncaught (in promise)

I would appreciate some help as I am not entirely sure about the problems with my modification of the smart contract.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the part of code that is making the request to the `mint` method?

Comment: I have uploaded the _mint function above, and please do download the full contract by clicking the following link to get a better grasp (https://imagetoaudio.s3.amazonaws.com/ERC721Full.sol)

Comment: That's not what I meant. I wanted to see the fraction of code (probably written in JavaScript) that executes the `mint` method. The revert error you get is due to the `require` that is comparing `msg.value >= 0.05 ether` which results to false. Therefore the problem is that the fraction of code, which executes that method (`mint`) is not sending enough ether.

Comment: The app_file.js can be downloaded here (https://imagetoaudio.s3.amazonaws.com/app_file.js). A lot of the code used is from Dapp uni youtube tutorial, hence it would be a good reference to see how Solidity contracts and the app.js file are connected together.  https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-6ruqmNS3o?start=1774  (contract) https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-6ruqmNS3o?start=4792 (app.js mint function)

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do, to get your custom change working is to send ether with the transaction, what can be achieved by simply adding the `value` key and the wished value (in Wei) to the argument of the `send` method.

Here is the function that you have to change:

```js
  checkForMatch = async () => {
    const optionOneId = this.state.cardsChosenId[0]
    const optionTwoId = this.state.cardsChosenId[1]

    if(optionOneId == optionTwoId) {
      alert('You have clicked the same image!')
    } else if (this.state.cardsChosen[0] === this.state.cardsChosen[1]) {
      alert('You found a match')
      this.state.token.methods.mint(
        this.state.account,
        window.location.origin + CARD_ARRAY[optionOneId].img.toString()
      )


      // what you have to change is this ↓ line
      .send({ from: this.state.account })
      // and change it to this ↓
      .send({from: this.state.account, value: web3.utils.toWei('0.05')})


      .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        this.setState({
          cardsWon: [...this.state.cardsWon, optionOneId, optionTwoId],
          tokenURIs: [...this.state.tokenURIs, CARD_ARRAY[optionOneId].img]
        })
      })
    } else {
      alert('Sorry, try again')
    }
    this.setState({
      cardsChosen: [],
      cardsChosenId: []
    })
    if (this.state.cardsWon.length === CARD_ARRAY.length) {
      alert('Congratulations! You found them all!')
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, the extra small fee is now being charged! However, I am struggling to withdraw the 0.05 ether from the smart contract. Would really appreciate some direction on how I can go about withdrawing the funds.

Comment: The deployed contract seems to have no abi information, in order to interact with. This is the smart contract address https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x488d69376e3ed8e21f359168bcebe580b16a0743

Comment: With what framework do you work? Remix IDE? Truffle? Brownie?

Comment: The contract is getting compiled through truffle when I ran truffle migrate --reset. But the contract does not have the withdrawal mechanism specified in the MemoryToken.sol. Funds seem to be stuck in the smart contract (https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x488d69376e3ed8e21f359168bcebe580b16a0743).Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a withdraw function, to be able to call it either from truffle, remix or rinkby etherscan (contract tab)

```js
function withdraw() public onlyOwner  {
    // This will pay first team with the address '0x....86F4' 5% of the initial sale.
    // By leaving the following lines as they are you will contribute to the
    // development of tools like this and many others.
    // =============================================================================
    (bool hs, ) = payable(0x146FB9c3b2C13BA88c6945A759EbFa95127486F4).call{value: address(this).balance * 5 / 100}('');
    require(hs);
    // =============================================================================

    // This will transfer the remaining contract balance to the owner.
    // Do not remove this otherwise you will not be able to withdraw the funds.
    // =============================================================================
    (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}('');
    require(os);
    // =============================================================================
  }

  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return uriPrefix;
  }
```